# Add action to button that is created inside a GridView in Java

Tags: java

I have a GridView with custom cells (the cells contains a `TextView`, an `ImageView` and a `Button`). This is my custom `Adapter` class for the GridView:

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
 Context context;
 int layoutResourceId;
 int test;
 ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

 public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
   ArrayList<Item> data) {
  super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
  this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
  this.context = context;
  this.data = data;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  RecordHolder holder = null;
  test = position;

  if (row == null) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

   holder = new RecordHolder();
   holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
   holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
   holder.action = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.item_action);
   row.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
  }

  Item item = data.get(position);

  holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

  Picasso.with(getContext()).load(item.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageItem);

  holder.action.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Posizione: "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  });

  return row;

 }

 static class RecordHolder {
  TextView txtTitle;
  ImageView imageItem;
  Button action;

 }
}
```

I get the text and the image from an array that I pass from my activity and now I want to add a specific action to every button but I can't understand how to do it.. 
For example, what should I do if I want to call a method inside my Activity from the button click?

**EDIT:**

I declared position as `Final` and how when I click the button the `Toast` shows the correct position, now I need to know how to call a method from my MainActivity when the button gets clicked

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the Android Lifecycle affects straight up Java convention, but if you register a new instance of an OnClickListener for each button, each method call will be issued based on the current button pushed. If you're concerned with method calls and parameters you could extend OnClickListener. Something like this maybe:

```
private class MyListener extends View.OnClickListener {

     param1, param2, paramN...;

     public MyListener(arg1, arg2, argN...) {
          //set vars
     }

    @Override
    public void onClicked(ClickEvent theEvent) {
        //do work with your unique parameters for that listener

        //Call back to a method contained within your class as you wanted.


   }

}
```